# Javascript dropdown list not not completing full task

Tags: javascript, php

Below is the javascript I adapted while following a online tutorial. The objective is to have a 2 dropdown lists the first queries the database and produces a list of options to choose from. After a selection is made the second list will alter its results based upon the selection in the first. However the second dropdown is not being populated and I think it in this piece of code, but I am very new to javascript. Is there something wrong here that I am not seeing. Here is the video for reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_mT6gD_dDE

```
enter code here
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("GetTaxon.php", success = function(data)
    {
        var options = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
        }

        $("#first_choice").append(options);

        $("#first_choice").change();
    });

    $("#first_choice").change(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("Get_FullName.php?taxon=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data)
        {
            var options = "";

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
            }

            $("#second_choice").html("");
            $("#second_choice").append(options);
        });
    });
});
```

The error I get is this I think this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
at Object.success (script.js:24)
at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Is there a way to avoid this using the toLowerCase argument? I would like it to accept all output if possible, however I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: what do you mean "something wrong"? Would you elaborate more?

Comment: The problem isn't `toLowerCase`, the problem is that you're trying to get it from `null`.  That in turn indicates that `data[i]` is not assigned a value.  That seems kinda weird since it's in a for loop and has to have a length to go into the loop. Use `console.log(data)` before the loop to see what data actually is.